# how to notify user in joomla when user assigned to a group

Tags: joomla2.5, usergroups

In the project of mine I made a component that creates a User for Joomla and Virtuemart via a form. Administrator requested that no group has to be assigned to the newly created user until administrator decides to. User has to be automatically activated too. Please don't ask me why, this what I have been asked to do :(

When Administrator assigns a userGroup to the user, an email should be sent to the user to notify the user of this action so user can login.

I couldnt find any solution for it, I cant find a trigger that notify me when user assigns to a UserGroup either so I make a plugin for it.

Joomla is 2.5.8

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JUtility/sendMail](http://docs.joomla.org/JUtility/sendMail) to send emails.

Now where to triggre email using sendMail?

Go to `/libraries/joomla/user/helper.php` file.

Inside, there is a method `public static function addUserToGroup($userId, $groupId)`.

Most probably this is the method which is called. You may extend/override this method to add a custom custom code to trigger an email if assigning a userid to groupid is successful.

You may put a check for boolean return value on this part.

```
// Store the user object.           
$user->save();
```

So if it is successful, the email will be triggered!

Hope it helps! Any better ideas are welcome.

Comment: Cool mate. I will test it and will put the result in here. Cheers